# Storing one value for each item in 2-Dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Luckily I came up with a decent title, describing what I was curious about.
While this is really hard for me to explain, I am doing my best.

I tried, storing values in 3D array as such:
`char arr[10][10][1];`
To copy a string I have to do it in `arr[y][x]`, (And I sadly I can't in just `arr[y]`)but then, because of a reason still unknown for me, I could *overflow* the buffer with `arr[8][8][8]`. Maybe because of the size of `char**` but anyway.
I couldn't find a slot to store a character for each item (x and y)

I tried, it the other way:
`char arr[1][10][10];`
Assuming that I have 1 item * x and y.
To store a string, I have to do it in `arr[0][y]`, which means the 3rd cell will be a character from the string.

So as a resume, I am trying to store one value for each character in x and y.
Do I really need 4D array for this?

---

**Additional clarification:**
I am aware what 1D and 2D arrays are for. Seems I can't understand the 3D array.
I thought that I can store an additional item for each character at y or x.
Example:

`char arr[y][x][z];`
Where y is the line, x is the column and z is the additional item that applies to all the characters.

Comment: `char arr[10][10][1];` is a 3-dimensional array of chars, not of strings, just so it's clear.

Comment: Isn't `char arr[10][10];` sufficient? Then store chars by `arr[x][y] = 'x';`.

Comment: @BennoZeeman that will store a character in a string given at x on a place given in y.

Comment: @Nit, so I have to create my own function for that?

Comment: @Protogrammer Why don't you begin with telling us what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Protogrammer I assumed you ment to store chars by saying "I couldn't find a slot to store a character for each item (x and y)". Expand your question by showing us what you're trying to do, like Nit said, preferably with code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

A string is an array of characters. An array of strings is therefore an array of arrays of characters. Why you think you need the 3rd dimension, I have no idea.

When you allocate a multi-dimensional array statically, you *must* specify the maximum number of items that it can contain. In this case, you must specify how many bytes long the string is allowed to be, including one byte for null termination. This is the right-most [] in the expression, in your case 1 byte.

So you haven't actually allocated any memory at all to store a string: 1 byte is enough to store the null termination and nothing else. This is why you get a crash/seg fault when you attempt [x][y][z] when z is any other value than 0. And you cannot store anything meaningful there either.

Size of char** has absolutely nothing to do with this whatsoever. Pointers are not arrays.

I'd strongly suggest that your study this C FAQ about [pointers and arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Now what you probably want to do is something like this:

```
char string_array [10][20+1]; // 10 strings each containing 20 letters + null

strcpy(string_array[0], "hello");
strcpy(string_array[1], "world");
...
printf("%s\n", string_array[0]);
printf("%s\n", string_array[1]);
...
```

Comment: Ehh imagine it like you want to store boolean expression for each character. if y contains lines and x contains columns, then z must determine if that character on yx is true or false.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the 3rd dimension as such .
you can use for example a[x][y];
and you can access this using *a[];

As you can also see that while using command line arguments where 2D array *argv[] is used to store a number of strings from command line. It explains you the best how 2D arrays are used.

For further reference you can have a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: I don't see where I ever mentioned confusion about 2D arrays and how they works..

Comment: yeah. but just reviewing that article would give a head start on how 2D and futher multidimensional array works